# how to listen to email event in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, connector

I am developing and simple application in blackberry JDE 6.
My application will listen to any incoming or outgoing event i.e SMS event, MMS event, Email Event. After the occurrence of those event. App will prompt user about event and will do **some** processing.

for listening to SMS and MMS event i am implementing the OutboundMessageListener interface and passing it to the MessageConnection class object as shown belowe.

i have found the protocol for SMS and MMS (sms:// and mms://) 
referred to this link [Connector class protocol support](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html)

for SMS and MMS i am using this code to listen to the events

```
MessageConnection sms= (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://:0"); 
sms.setMessageListener(customPhoneListener);            

MessageConnection mms = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("mms://0");
mms.setMessageListener(customPhoneListener);
```

But for email i am not able to find any protocol like sms and mms

how can i listen to email events any idea ?? 
any help appreciated :)

I have tried using the below code (jst to try even if i knw its not correct) to listen to email event but no luck as expected

```
MessageConnection email = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("email://0");
email.setMessageListener(customPhoneListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.event.FolderListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/event/FolderListener.html) and [Store](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/Store.html).addFolderListener()

Comment: thnx for the reply :) well , will this help me listening to SMS and MMS folders ?? and one more thing i am using Simulator to develop my app so do u knw how to setup BES to start with email services ???